# Adding external non-bower scripts into Yeoman

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, bower

Created an app via angularjs yeoman generator and running a grunt server

Trying to figure out how I can add external scripts that are not in bower.

Everytime I just add it to the index.html file, it gets erased when the server does a livereload

Answer (score 0):

You are probably accidentally editing the file in the .tmp folder instead of the actual index.html file in the app folder.  If you're using SublimeText it can be helpful to exclude the dist and .tmp folders.